# Missing attributes from type failes silently in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, types, utility

### Problem

I have created an IEntity interface that all objects in the client application are derived from. This has attributes that are dictated by the .Net Core API.

When the client creates a new object locally, it doesn't have these attributes, so it needs them removed. I've tried to do it using the `IDraft<T>` interface.

The problem is that Typescript and ESLint don't seem to care that the object I've created doesn't match the type `IDraft<IPerson>`.

### Code

```
export abstract interface IEntity {
  // ID: A UUID for the entity.
  readonly id: string;
  // Date created.
  readonly createdAt: Date;
  // Date modified.
  readonly modifiedAt: Date;
}

//
// IDraft - A local-only draft of type of Entity.
//
// Strips IEntity attributes from the generic interface `T`.
//
export abstract interface IDraft<T>
  extends Omit<T, 'id' | 'createdAt' | 'modifiedAt'> {}
```

```
import { IEntity } from '../global.types';

type PersonType = 'applicant' | 'admin' | 'clientuser';

export interface IPerson extends Required<IEntity> {
  firstName: string;
  familyName?: string;
  email: string;
  type: PersonType;
}
```

```
const newPerson: IDraft<IPerson> = {
        // Missing id
        firstName: 'Bruce',
        email: 'test@test',
    } as IDraft<IPerson>;
```

### Expected behaviour

- Typescript throws an error because `newPerson` does not match `IDraft<IPerson>`.

### Actual behaviour

- Typescript does not produce an error, making the type useless.

Comment: `IDraft<IPerson>` is `IPerson` without 'id', 'createdAt' and 'modifiedAt' fields. How does `IPerson` look like? Missing `id` must not produce an error since `IDraft` removes it from `IPerson`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the
`as IDraft<IPerson>`
The 'as' keyword asserts the type as IDraft

[Type assertion in ts docs here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)

Comment: Thank you, it still doesn't throw an error though.